# code is not working to move snake in java

Tags: java

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getKeyCode();
    if (i == KeyEvent.VK_A && direction != RIGHT && direction != DOWN && direction != UP)
            direction = LEFT;

    if (i == KeyEvent.VK_D && direction != LEFT && direction != UP && direction != DOWN)
            direction = RIGHT;

    if (i == KeyEvent.VK_W && direction != DOWN && direction != LEFT && direction != RIGHT)
            direction = UP;

    if (i == KeyEvent.VK_S && direction != UP && direction != LEFT && direction != RIGHT )
            direction = DOWN;


    if(i == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        if(over)
            startGame();
        else
            paused = !paused;           
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As I see this, you only allow to change the direction to the one you already use. you set the direction to left, when the direction is not right, down and up -> so it is already left?

Comment: Try to add some brackets { } to be your code more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just wan't to disable a 180 degree turn and not a 90 degree as @ThomasBöhm already mentioned.

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int i = e.getKeyCode();
        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_A && direction != RIGHT)
                direction = LEFT;

        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_D && direction != LEFT)
                direction = RIGHT;

        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_W && direction != DOWN)
                direction = UP;

        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_S && direction != UP)
                direction = DOWN;


        if(i == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            if(over)
                startGame();
            else
                paused = !paused;           
    }
```